# Better way to filter or group data in python

Tags: python

I am totally new to python and struggling to know how can I filter or group my data in better way.
Let me give context. I am using `Django` and `cursor` for complex query. After I get results from query, I want to group my data in my way:

```py
# Some query gives me sorted data (in DESC order)
# Query already grouped data by state, item and distance
rows = cursor.fetchall()
```

Data I retrieve looks something like this:

```
|-----|-------|---------|---------------|
|state| item  | distance|selling_percent|
|-----|-------|---------|---------------|
| A   | item1 | 107     | 55            |
| A   | item2 | 20      | 45            |
| A   | item3 | 65      | 40            |
| B   | item4 | 88      | 30            |
| B   | item2 | 32      | 25            |
| B   | item1 | 100     | 20            |
| C   | item2 | 170     | 10            |
| C   | item3 | 184     | 5             |
| C   | item4 | 1       | 2             |
|-----|-------|---------|---------------|
```

How I want result is by following steps:

1. Create new blank list (called result now on)
2. Start from first row and check whether row with `state` already exist in result or not. If not, check whether `item` exist in result or not. If *does not*, then push that row in result.
3. If either sate or row exist in list, then skip that row
4. After populating result, sort result list by `distance`

End result would be like this:

```
|-----|-------|---------|---------------|
|state| item  | distance|selling_percent|
|-----|-------|---------|---------------|
| A   | item1 | 107     | 55            |
| B   | item4 | 88      | 30            |
| C   | item2 | 170     | 10            |
|-----|-------|---------|---------------|
```

It looks very simple but I really want to know nice way. Currently I am doing like this:

```py
d = defaultdict(dict)
for col, row in zip(cursor.description, rows):
  state = row[0]
  item = row[1]
  distance = row[2]
  selling_percent = row[3]

  # If state or item exists, skip row
  if (state in d) | (item in d[state]):
    continue

  d[state][item] = {
    'distance': distance,
    'selling_percent': selling_percent,
  }

result = []
# d contains nested dictionary, we want is list of straight dictionary
for state in d:
  for item in d[state]:
    result.append({
      'state': state,
      'item': item,
      **d[state][item]
    })
# sort final result by distance
result = sorted(result, key=lambda k: k['distance'])
```

I found some nice libraries like `numpy` or `pandas` but I found it might be not useful here. I am posting question here to learn better way for such logic.

I will appreciate some help!

Comment: Why don't you group the data inside the query?

Comment: Could you add the result you want to see as well ? Would make it a lot easier to give suggestions. TYIA !

Comment: @MushifAliNawaz Query already grouped data by state, item and distance. I don't know any way in query too how can I filter data in that way! But I also want to know some technique in python too!

Comment: @fixatd Thanks for suggestion! I added expected result in that!